# how to open .d01 foxpro file

Tags: database, foxpro, dbf

I am building a basic POS app for my cousin's pharmacy store so that he can dump the software he is currently using and save on license cost.All the medicines name which he has painfully entered into the software have been stored in a file with .d01 extension.
What i want is a way to read the contents of the .d01 file programmatically so that i can import the name of the medicines into my app.
The s/w from which my cousin uses is built in Foxpro(coz i see a lot of .cdx,.idx,.dbf files) and the file which i want to import is with .d01 extension. when i open the file in notepad it is something like this
http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/5528/foxpro.jpg

So I assume its somekind of database table or something. So can anyone please help me in reading this file, as i am not at all aware of foxpro.

Thanks a lot in advance to all those who take out time to reply.

---

hey guys thank you very much for replying so promptly.. I tried the solution suggested by Otávio and it worked, i will now write a small utility to read the dbf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a good chance of being just a regular .dbf file. Copy it somewhere safe, change the extension to dbf and see if you can open it from foxpro.

Comment: You can open any DBF no matter what the extension is:

USE Pro.D01 IN 0 SHARED

Answer (score 1):

Although it may have .cdx files, the actual paste of the file does not appear to be a visually recognizable header format of a VFP table... even if part of a database container.  The characters around each column name don't look right.  It may be from another language that also utilized "Compound Indexes".  I even saw an article about Sybase's IAnywhere too.  If worst-case scenario, and it is determined to be a possible fixed-length per row and no dynamic column sizes, you might take the file, strip off what appears to be the header and leave just the data and stream read it in based on how many constant characters are determined for the length.  yeah, brute force, but just an option.  Again, it doesn't LOOK like a VFP table.

BTW, what is the name of the software he is using...  I'd look into that to see if any other type of indication to its source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks sort of like a DBF file - maybe Clipper or something.